# Add onReceivedSslError to the Android Webview's client

Tags: nativescript

We have a problem in the application that we're working on right now that some https images don't show.

The fix is easy: implement a WebView client that overrides `onReceivedSslError` and set it as the client of the webview:

```
const MyWebViewClient = android.webkit.WebViewClient.extend({
    onReceivedSslError: function (view, handler) {
        handler.proceed();
    }
});

webview.android.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

The problem with this is that we'll lose all the events from NativeScript as it will override NS' own webview client.

I've also find out that the Android's client is attached to the `.android` property of the native component, so I've tried this:

```
webview.android.client.onReceivedSslError = function (view, handler) {
    handler.proceed();
};
```

But doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how/if I can achieve both allowing content with SSL error in my webview AND keep the NativeScript functionality added by the NS webview client ?

Comment: try the solution provided here (overwriting the NativeScript web view implementation) - https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/webview-bypass-ssl-error/3313/3

Comment: @NickIliev as far as I can tell, the first one copy&pastes the whole class from NS source code to it's code and just adds the specific ssl method. This is somewhat fine, but will make future fixes and improvements coming from NS unavailable to us. The second one suggests to manually edit a file from node_modules, which is not a valid solution.

Comment: @NickIliev any idea why this was discontinued: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/1196 ? This would have been the perfect solution.

Comment: Hey @surdu - I can't really say why the WebViewClient has not exported anymore (there was some major refactoring some time ago and it might be unintended) -0 however as NativeScript is open-source you can create a PR and implement the wanted feature (either handling SSL error or exposing the WebViewCline... or perhaps even both)

Comment: Meanwhile, I have created this demo application to demonstrate the technique described in one of the forum threads - https://github.com/NickIliev/NS-Issues/tree/master/stackoverflow/webViewClient

Comment: @NickIliev can you please add you example, the discourse link and what else you think fit as the answer, as I went with this solution for now. Thank you!